# Show strings unserialize wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a problem, to obtain the values ​​of the table wp_postmeta and meta_key "construccion_value", the results are serialized. This is the code I use.

```
$datos = get_post_custom_values('construccion_value');
                $datos= maybe_unserialize($datos);
                print_r($datos);
```

When do I print these results appear

```
Array ( [0] => a:2:{i:0;s:0:"aaa";i:1;s:3:"sss";} )
```

My question is how do I get the string "aaa" and "sss" respectively.
Now try it with maybe_unserialized and unserialized, but without results on screen.

Comment: Define "without results". Have you tried the native `unserialize()`

Comment: Yes i tried with unserialize, but no results. :)

Comment: Your `$datos` is an array. You need to use the first item via `$datos[0]` in the `unserialize` function.

Comment: Yes, but `datos[0]`, no show nothing, any data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what `maybe_unserialize` is, but `unserialize` will work.

Comment: Don't Work dude, look:

$datos = get_post_custom_values('construccion_value');
$datos = unserialize($datos);
print_r($datos);

On screen : "Warning: unserialize() expects parameter 1 to be string................."

Comment: Then your `$datos` is not valid. Check that variable.

Comment: Oh sorry, you should be using `unserialize($datos[0])`

Comment: `$datos = get_post_custom_values('construccion_value');
print_r($datos);`

On Screen: "`Array ( [0] => a:2:{i:0;s:0:"aaa";i:1;s:3:"sss";} )`"

I am think it is not error variable.

Comment: Interesting - because you just told us `$datos` = `Array ( [0] => a:2:{i:0;s:0:"aaa";i:1;s:3:"sss";} )` ...

Comment: Yes, and I get the string "aaa" and "sss" respectively.

Comment: Probably because this isn't a valid serialized string. `s:0:"aaa"` is wrong... should be `s:3:"aaa"`

Comment: Wuop!, now appear `Array ( [0] => aaa [1] => sss )`

Comment: Ok now you can access that via... `$str = unserialize($datos[0]); echo $str[0]; // aaa`

Answer (score 0):

Try =

```
$datos = unserialize($datos[0]);
```